# Django - Integrity error when tried deleting a project

Tags: python, django, model

I only have one model and that's the only one I need. How to design the model in a way that I don't get the foreign key constraint error?

Here's my model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Inititated', 'Inititated'),
        ('Paused', 'Paused'),
        ('In progress', 'In progress'),
        ('Aborted', 'Aborted'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed')
        )

    PHASE = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
        ('6', '6'),
        ('7', '7'),
        ('8', '8'),
        ('9', '9'),
        ('10', '10')
    )

    p_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    p_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    c_mail = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    init_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    ect = models.DateField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, choices=STATUS)
    collabs = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    phase = models.IntegerField(null=True, choices=PHASE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_name

    @property
    def phase_percentage(self):
        return self.phase * 10
```

Comment: show us how are you trying to delete it, in your `views.py`, attach code to the question

Comment: I haven't added any code to views.py. I am deleting from Django Admin

Comment: You don't use `ForeignKey` in this model. You are definitely hiding something :) Paste full traceback.

Comment: raise IntegrityError(
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'accounts_project_phase' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: accounts_project_phase.project_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in accounts_project.id.

Comment: Ok, now I think I know, what's the problem. Posting answer in a sec. Add that to main post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `phase = models.IntegerField(null=True, choices=PHASE)`. Because, as we can see it's an `IntegerField`, yet you are giving it choices with strings:

```
PHASE = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    (...)
    ('10', '10')
)
```

Change it to:

```
PHASE = (
    (1, "1"),
    (2, "2"),
    ...
    (3, "3")
)
```

Because first value is the value actually passing to the field, and second is "human readable" value, that shows in rendered forms etc.

Before deleting you might need to change that field value in your objects.

Comment: Tried what you suggested in your answer, but the problem isn't resolved. Here's the traceback: https://gist.github.com/thekaranatic/f9197d5204e6fda42e1ce0a0b1f94a8c

Comment: @thekaranatic add this to your Question, because I don't know how to help you and other users might need to see it.